ROS2 Humble in Windows 10, compiling fails, catkin_pkg missing
I installed ROS2 Humble in Windows 10.
Followed the official tutorial. https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Installation/Windows-Install-Binary.html# so far, it works, can use rqt and rviz.
I am also able to call the preinstalled packages and can see the topic in rqt.
C:\ros2_ws>ros2 run demo_nodes_cpp talker
[INFO] [1731536860.308881000] [talker]: Publishing: 'Hello World: 1'
[INFO] [1731536861.308848900] [talker]: Publishing: 'Hello World: 2'
[INFO] [1731536862.308845600] [talker]: Publishing: 'Hello World: 3'
[INFO] [1731536868.082521000] [rclcpp]: signal_handler(signum=2)

But I cannot compile. Here is how I do it: I sourced the environment, created a workspace, created a new package.
**********************************************************************
** Visual Studio 2019 Developer Command Prompt v16.11.41
** Copyright (c) 2021 Microsoft Corporation
**********************************************************************

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community>call C:\opt\ros2_humble\local_setup.bat
"[rti_connext_dds_cmake_module][warning] RTI Connext DDS environment script not found (\resource\scripts\rtisetenv_x64Win64VS2017.bat). RTI Connext DDS will not be available at runtime, unless you already configured PATH manually."

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community>cd \ros2_ws\src

C:\ros2_ws\src>ros2 pkg create --build-type ament_cmake --license Apache-2.0 test
going to create a new package
package name: test
destination directory: C:\ros2_ws\src
package format: 3
version: 0.0.0
description: TODO: Package description
maintainer: ['']
licenses: ['Apache-2.0']
build type: ament_cmake
dependencies: []
creating folder .\test
creating .\test\package.xml
creating source and include folder
creating folder .\test\src
creating folder .\test\include\test
creating .\test\CMakeLists.txt

That worked so far, and it creates the structure with directories and files.
But the build fails. Its an empty package, so there are no dependencies.
C:\ros2_ws\src>cd ..

C:\ros2_ws>colcon build
Starting >>> test
--- stderr: test
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\opt\ros2_humble\share\ament_cmake_core\cmake\core\package_xml_2_cmake.py", line 22, in <module>
    from catkin_pkg.package import parse_package_string
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'catkin_pkg'
CMake Error at C:/opt/ros2_humble/share/ament_cmake_core/cmake/core/ament_package_xml.cmake:95 (message):
  execute_process(C:/ProgramData/anaconda3/python.exe
  C:/opt/ros2_humble/share/ament_cmake_core/cmake/core/package_xml_2_cmake.py
  C:/ros2_ws/src/test/package.xml
  C:/ros2_ws/build/test/ament_cmake_core/package.cmake) returned error code 1
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/opt/ros2_humble/share/ament_cmake_core/cmake/core/ament_package_xml.cmake:49 (_ament_package_xml)
  C:/opt/ros2_humble/share/ament_lint_auto/cmake/ament_lint_auto_find_test_dependencies.cmake:31 (ament_package_xml)
  CMakeLists.txt:23 (ament_lint_auto_find_test_dependencies)


---
Failed   <<< test [7.48s, exited with code 1]

Summary: 0 packages finished [7.74s]
  1 package failed: test
  1 package had stderr output: test
WNDPROC return value cannot be converted to LRESULT
TypeError: WPARAM is simple, so must be an int object (got NoneType)

I tried the same with the examples I downloaded from GitHub. Humble, minimal publisher\subscriber
C:\ros2_ws>colcon build
Starting >>> examples_rclcpp_minimal_publisher
Starting >>> examples_rclcpp_minimal_subscriber
--- stderr: examples_rclcpp_minimal_publisher
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\opt\ros2_humble\share\ament_cmake_core\cmake\core\package_xml_2_cmake.py", line 22, in <module>
    from catkin_pkg.package import parse_package_string
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'catkin_pkg'
CMake Error at C:/opt/ros2_humble/share/ament_cmake_core/cmake/core/ament_package_xml.cmake:95 (message):
  execute_process(C:/ProgramData/anaconda3/python.exe
  C:/opt/ros2_humble/share/ament_cmake_core/cmake/core/package_xml_2_cmake.py
  C:/ros2_ws/src/minimal_publisher/package.xml
  C:/ros2_ws/build/examples_rclcpp_minimal_publisher/ament_cmake_core/package.cmake)
  returned error code 1
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/opt/ros2_humble/share/ament_cmake_core/cmake/core/ament_package_xml.cmake:49 (_ament_package_xml)
  C:/opt/ros2_humble/share/ament_lint_auto/cmake/ament_lint_auto_find_test_dependencies.cmake:31 (ament_package_xml)
  CMakeLists.txt:47 (ament_lint_auto_find_test_dependencies)


---
Failed   <<< examples_rclcpp_minimal_publisher [16.3s, exited with code 1]
Aborted  <<< examples_rclcpp_minimal_subscriber [16.5s]

Summary: 0 packages finished [16.9s]
  1 package failed: examples_rclcpp_minimal_publisher
  1 package aborted: examples_rclcpp_minimal_subscriber
  2 packages had stderr output: examples_rclcpp_minimal_publisher examples_rclcpp_minimal_subscriber
WNDPROC return value cannot be converted to LRESULT
TypeError: WPARAM is simple, so must be an int object (got NoneType)
pip install catkin_pkg and pip install rosdep return Requirement already satisfied:

Am I doing something wrong? Same steps work in Ubuntu. Why do I get the error, and it insists on catkin? That was ROS1.
